# "cd" in a function works, except when it doesn't

Tags: bash, cd-command

The first thing I do after cd'ing to a directory is to use "ls", as I imagine is the case for a lot of people. So I decided to define a function in my .bashrc to do both together. This is what I came up with:

```
cs() {
    if [[ ! "$1" ]] && [[ ! "$HOME" ]]
    then
        echo "I am completely lost and can't go home!"
        exit 1
    fi
    cd "$1" && ls --group-directories-first -h --color=auto
}
```

This worked in every situation but one: when I didn't pass it any arguments. With or without $HOME set, it would just do nothing and exit. I eventually dismembered that first line and arrived at this:

```
cs() {
    if [[ ! "$1" ]]
    then
        if [[ ! "$HOME" ]]
        then
            echo "I am completely lost and can't go home!"
            exit 1
        else
            cd && ls --group-directories-first -h --color=auto
        fi
    else
        cd "$1" && ls --group-directories-first -h --color=auto
    fi
}
```

This code works exactly as I intended. In between the two, I had a version with a very strange behavior (unfortunately I saved over it, but the differences to these two versions were very small) in which if I evoked "cs" with an argument, it would give me the output of "ls" for that directory... but would not change directories! Since the code is only passing arguments to "cd" and ls is falling back on the default behavior of working on the current directory (which was also the case in this lost version), plus at no point did I ever put a second "cd" after the "ls" in the same code block, this shouldn't even be possible as far as I know.

I just want to understand what's going on here. I'm just starting to learn scripting and this, which I thought would be a very simple task, seems to have turned into a great learning opportunity. Why are these functions that seem to me pretty much equivalent behaving differently?

Comment: How exactly did you run these functions? `cd` should affect the whole process (but not if it were run in a subprocess of the main shell process).

Comment: @thrig I just added the function to my ~/.bashrc, ran source ~/.bashrc and then called "cs some-directory" I also made a bash script that defines then calls the function and the behavior was the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to run `cd` with the list of original arguments given to the function and then run your `ls` command.

```bash
cs () {
    cd "$@" && ls --group-directories-first --human-readable --color=auto
}
```

The expansion `"$@"` will be nothing (at all) if the function wasn't called with any arguments, causing `cd` to change to the home directory of the current user or fail in whatever way is appropriate.  The expansion will otherwise be a quoted list of arguments (note that `cd` generally can take more than a single argument).

The intrinsic logic of the `cd` command already handles the cases of receiving no arguments with `HOME` being unset, so your function does not have to get involved.

In general, you probably want to avoid using `exit` in functions as that would exit the current shell.  Instead, if you wish to return a non-zero exit status from a function, use, e.g. `return 1`.

As for your comments about `cd` not successfully changing directories:  This could happen if you run your function (or just `cd`) in a subshell, as in `(cd /)` or `cat somefile | while ...; do cd ...; done` (where each part of the pipeline runs in a subshell).  The `cd` call succeeds, and the current directory *is* changed, but the changes are made to the local environment of the subshell and will not be visible in the parent shell. There is no way for a subshell to change the environment of its parent shell.

Comment: @Kusalanada Thank you very much. This cleared up some confusion in my head. And it works! Do you mind if I ask a couple of follow-up questions?

Is being inside a loop considered a subshell? And why did you use "$@" instead of "$1"? I have a few other simple functions defined in my bashrc and I've been using $1, should I change that?

Comment: @Calibre The body of a loop is not separate subshell (although it may _contain_ subshells, for example the parts of pipelines).  The reason for using `"$@"` is mentioned in the answer: We want to pass _all_ arguments to `cd`, no matter if there are zero, one, or many of them.  If you use `"$1"`, you only ever allow the user to pass a singular argument, so they would not be able to say e.g. `cs -P /some/path` (see `help cd` in the bash shell for what `cd -P` does).

Comment: @Kisalanada Thanks again! I did some reading and I think I understand now. I didn't know that there were any options to "cd"...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cs() {
>     ...
>     cd "$1" && ls --group-directories-first -h --color=auto
> }
> ```
>
> This worked in every situation but one: when I didn't pass it any
> arguments.

When you don't have any arguments, `$1` is unset (as are `$2`, `$3`, ...). But when you expand that unset parameter in quotes, in `"$1"` it acts the same as one with an empty value, i.e. it expands to the empty string. This is different from no argument, e.g. compare `ls` with `ls ""` or  `unset foo; ls "$foo"`.

In the case of `cd`, the behaviour in Bash is that calling `cd` with no arguments goes to `$HOME`, while calling `cd` with an empty string as the argument goes silently to the current directory.

<sub>(That depends on the shell and if you use `-P`. The underlying `chdir()` function call is supposed to give an error if the argument is an empty string, and it looks like Bash exposes that with `cd -P`. Some other shells just `chdir()` to `.` or the current directory, and ksh gives a "bad directory" error for both `cd ""` and `cd -P ""`.)</sub>

To pass all the arguments of the function to `cd`, use `cd "$@"`. Unlike other double-quoted expansions (which produce one string), `"$@"` is magic, and produces the positional parameters intact, as distinct strings, however many there are (or distinct shell "words", resulting in distinct arguments to the command). Hence with no arguments, `cd "$1"` is the same as `cd ""`, while `cd "$@"` is the same as just `cd`.

> With or without $HOME set, it would just do nothing and exit.

I can't see why the test for `$HOME` would not work, so I won't comment on that.

Comment: @ikkachu Thank you! I never would have guessed that there was a difference between "no arguments" and "an empty argument"...